# PDO query error after server migration and/or PHP upgrade

Tags: php, pdo

I have a small app running using PDO and after a server migration and PHP upgrade I'm now getting the following error

```
Warning: PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: mode must be an integer in var/www/xxxxxxxx
```

The line it references is

```
$statement = $this->_connection->Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE SOMECOL = '$col' LIMIT 1", $this->_connection);
```

I've been looking around google for awhile and there doesn't seem to be any fix. I've tried setting the default fetchmode using `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` but the error doesn't change.

Appreciate they help :)

Comment: Remove the second `$this->_connection` argument, read the argument list for [`PDO::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) - you'll see that passing the connection object to the second argument makes no sense. It looks like you probably migrated from ext/mysql, this mechanism of passing the connection to the database calls is no longer required with PDO. Also please learn about [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: When _connection is generated, somewhere I think the error mode is set to an illegal value. Can you check that up?

Comment: Could you also supply a copy of the source code for the method Query(); since no one can tell what the implementation is... i.e. $this->_connection->Query($query,$connection)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sending `$this->_connection` as a parameter there is wrong and not expected by PDO Query

> PDOStatement PDO::query ( string $statement )
>
> PDOStatement PDO::query ( string $statement , int $PDO::FETCH_COLUMN , int $colno )
>
> PDOStatement PDO::query ( string $statement , int $PDO::FETCH_CLASS , string $classname , array $ctorargs )
>
> PDOStatement PDO::query ( string $statement , int $PDO::FETCH_INTO , object $object )

That second parameter, if it is there, has to be an `int`

Source: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: Yep that was it! No longer need to pass the connection. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What's confusing about your code is that you're using non-standard names when performing your query:

```
$this->_connection->Query
```

I would write as:

```
$this->dbh->query
```

which would instantly make me think that ->query is actually `PDO::query()` and not some custom function of a wrapper class.

So, in this case the second parameter of `PDO::query()` should be a fetch mode, and adding the connection itself (which is of type `PDO`, not an integer) is thus, completely redundant, but I do understand that you were influenced by coding patterns used in mysql and mysqli extension drivers, which are now considered outdated/obsolete.